# How to display dropdown in angular material

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am new to angular material. So I am trying to do form using angular material. I am able to display input field. As it has no value, the field name will look like placeholder and if user clicks on the input field the field name will set as title and able to enter the value.

I am trying to display dropdown same as material input field. Intially if there is no value selected, the field name will look like placeholder with arrow at right corner. If user clicks the dropdown field, the field name need to be set as title and dropdown should open.

I tried but I am facing some issue in dropdown.

```
<form name="pForm" role="form">
<!--Personal Info Col-->    
<div class="row form-row1">
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (pForm.fname.$dirty || pForm.$submitted) && pForm.fname.$invalid }" >

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="aname" ng-model="model.aname" required/>
<span class="highlight"></span>
<span class="bar"></span>
<label class="control-label l_font field-name" for="aname"> Name of Account *</label>    
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (pForm.lname.$dirty || pForm.$submitted) && pForm.lname.$invalid }" class="help-block">

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="dname" ng-model="model.dname" required/>
<span class="highlight"></span>
<span class="bar"></span>
<label class="control-label l_font field-name">Display Name *</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (pForm.dname.$dirty || pForm.$submitted) && pForm.dname.$invalid}" >

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="acode" ng-model="model.acode" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z0-9_.]*$/" ng-minlength = "1"/> 
<span class="highlight"></span>
<span class="bar"></span>
<label class="control-label l_font field-name" for="acode">Account Code *
</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row form-row1">
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (pForm.caddress.$dirty || pForm.$submitted) && pForm.caddress.$invalid }" class="help-block">         
<!--<select class="form-control select2" name="segment" ng-model="model.segment" ng-options="item for item in segments" style="width: 100%;" required>
<option value class disabled selected>Select</option>                       
</select>-->

<div class="mad-select" class="group" required>
  <ul>
    <li data-value="1">Option 1</li>
    <li data-value="2 foo">Option 2</li>
    <li data-value="3 bar">Option 3</li>
    <li data-value="4">Option 4</li>
    <li data-value="5">Option long desc 5</li>
    <li data-value="6">Option 6</li>
    <li data-value="7">Option 7</li>
    <li data-value="8">Option 8</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="hidden" name="myOptions" value="3 bar">
</div>
<span class="highlight"></span>
<span class="bar"></span>
<label class="control-label l_font field-name">Segment</label>
    /* Script to display dropdown */
<script>
var madSelectHover = 0;
  $(".mad-select").each(function() {
    var $input = $(this).find("input"),
        $ul = $(this).find("> ul"),
        $ulDrop =  $ul.clone().addClass("mad-select-drop");
    $(this)
      .append('<i class="material-icons">arrow_drop_down</i>', $ulDrop)
      .on({
      hover : function() { madSelectHover ^= 1; },
      click : function() { $ulDrop.toggleClass("show"); }
    });
    // PRESELECT
    $ul.add($ulDrop).find("li[data-value='"+ $input.val() +"']").addClass("selected");
    // MAKE SELECTED
    $ulDrop.on("click", "li", function(evt) {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      $input.val($(this).data("value")); // Update hidden input value
      $ul.find("li").eq($(this).index()).add(this).addClass("selected")
        .siblings("li").removeClass("selected");
    });
    // UPDATE LIST SCROLL POSITION
    $ul.on("click", function() {
      var liTop = $ulDrop.find("li.selected").position().top;
      $ulDrop.scrollTop(liTop + $ulDrop[0].scrollTop);
    });
  });
  // CLOSE ALL OPNED
  $(document).on("mouseup", function(){
    if(!madSelectHover) $(".mad-select-drop").removeClass("show");
  });    
</script>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</form>



.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    /* border-radius: 4px; */
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    /* -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075); */
    /* box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075); */
    /* -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s; */
    /*-o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
     transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;*/
}



/* style for input box */
     .group        { 
  position:relative; 
  margin-bottom:45px; 
}
input         {
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  border:none;

}
input:focus     { outline:none; }

label          {
  /*color:#999;*/ 
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:normal;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  left:5px;
  top:10px;
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label     {
    top:-20px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#333;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.highlight {
  position:absolute;
  height:60%; 
  /*width:100px;*/ 
  top:25%; 
  left:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0.5;
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ .highlight {
  animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}

/* ANIMATIONS ================ */
@keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from  { background:#5264AE; }
  to    { width:0; background:transparent; }
}

    .field-name {
        left: 15px;
        top: 5px;
    }

    /* ./ style for input box - END ./ */

    /* style for select dropdown box */

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: transparent;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 1px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.3);
}

*{box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;}

body{
  font: 16px/24px Roboto, sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa;
}


/*
MAD-SELECT by Roko CB
*/
.mad-select .material-icons{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.mad-select{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  padding-right: 8px;
}
.mad-select ul {
  list-style: none;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0; padding:0;
}
.mad-select li{
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height:24px;
  line-height:24px;
  display: none;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: initial;
}
.mad-select > ul:first-of-type{
   max-width:120px; /* COMMENT FOR AUTO WIDTH */
}
.mad-select > ul:first-of-type li.selected{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 24px);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.mad-select i.material-icons{
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
/*jQ*/
.mad-select ul.mad-select-drop{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  visibility: hidden; opacity:0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.24s;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.mad-select ul.mad-select-drop.show{
  visibility: visible; opacity: 1;
  max-height: 160px; /* COMMENT IF YOU DON?T NEED MAX HEIGHT */
}
.mad-select ul.mad-select-drop li{
  display: block;
  transition: background 0.24s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mad-select ul.mad-select-drop li.selected{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.07);
}
.mad-select ul.mad-select-drop li:hover{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
}

    /* ./ style for select dropdown box - END ./ */
```

[input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KdBn.png)

[After selecting the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEDwF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not seems to be using angular-material tags, you are mixing up jquery and angular,

To use material with angular, add the necessary references for angular-material

```
 <link data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-animate@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-aria@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-aria.js"></script>
```

and inject ngMaterial as a dependency to your Module,

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["ngMaterial"]);
```

**DEMO FOR SELECT**

```js
// Code goes here


var app = angular.module('app', ["ngMaterial"]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.categories = [
            "test1 with 001" ,
            "test2 with 002" 
            ];
      $scope.Print = function(){
        alert($scope.model);
      }
      
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-animate@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-aria@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div layout="row">
    <md-select placeholder="Select" ng-model="model">
      <md-option ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{category}}">
        {{category}}
      </md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But for me the name of the dropdown field should look like placeholder and if user clicks on the dropdown the field name should move up and display as heading and allow to select the value from dropdown.

Comment: I want like this (https://app.lendingkart.com/lkart/check_eligibility_direct.html#!/home?from=applyNow). can you help me.